# using date function to query

Tags: oracle, plsql, date-arithmetic

I have the following table

Alarm (AlarmID INT, InstalledDate Date)

Given that the alarm need to be replace every 5 years, how do i display all the alarms that is due for replacement in the next 6 months?

I tried the following and there was no result:

```
SELECT AlarmID
FROM   Alarm
WHERE  Add_months(InstalledDate, 60)
BETWEEN SYSDATE AND Add_months(SYSDATE, 6);
```

Comment: Something like SELECT * FROM ALARM WHERE (InstallDate + 5 years - 6 months) <= NOW. Use the right dialect of SQL to do the date addition. That's off the top of my head, test it in SQL for real to get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I tried the following and there was no result:"

The query you propose looks correct, so perhaps you don't have any ALARMS which are five years old?

---

> "it seems like there is a difference using BETWEEN SYSDATE AND
>   Add_months(SYSDATE, 6) compare to BETWEEN Add_months(SYSDATE, 6) AND
>   SYSDATE;"

The BETWEEN operator demands that we pass the two values in a specific order, lower bound then upper bound.  So this filter is true:

```
where date '2012-03-01' between date '2012-01-01'  and date '2012-06-01'
```

whereas this is false:

```
where date '2012-03-01' between date '2012-06-01'  and date '2012-01-01'
```

Perhaps this seems unfair, but [the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions011.htm#sthref2006) makes it clearer by translating the BETWEEN operator into `lt` and `gt` statements:

```
where date '2012-03-01' >= date '2012-01-01'  
and   date '2012-03-01' <= date '2012-06-01'
```

If you swap the values of the second and third expressions you'll see why the reversed order returns false.

Comment: I figure out what's wrong, it seems like there is a difference using BETWEEN SYSDATE AND Add_months(SYSDATE, 6) **compare to** BETWEEN Add_months(SYSDATE, 6) AND SYSDATE;